# How to call a variable from one script into another script with R?

Tags: r, variables

I explain my problem : I have two R scripts. I create a variable into the first script that I would like to call into the secondd script. The problem is that to get this variable into the first script, I need to write some R lines, but I don't want to rewrite these lines into the second script.

Any help?

Edit : From a previous topic, I tried these lines in my second R script:

```
loadRData <- function(fileName) {
  #loads an RData file, and returns it
  load(fileName)
  print(ls())
  n <- readline(prompt="combs")  #combs is the name of my variable 
  get(ls()[as.matrix(n)])
}

select_var <- loadRData('RHO_COR.R') #RHO_COR.R is the name of my first script , I execute this command in my second script
```

But I get a warning message :

```
Error in load(fileName) :
bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘RHO_COR.R’ has magic number 'libra'
   Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at `source`.

Comment: You mean I should `source` my first code into my seconde one ?.

Comment: Yes, sourcing the script is an option. Just `source(myfile.R)` will execute the whole script (all variables are loaded). If you really want just one variable from the script there are tricks to do that (e.g. using `rm`, rewriting your script of using optional arguments in `source`).

Comment: Alternative, write the variable to a file, then read it back in. See `?write.csv` and `?read.csv`. Using source is easier, and faster, but may result in unwanted variables, packages or functions loaded.

Comment: I don't know how could I use `rm` ? If I do something like this : #script1 `x=my_variable`  ; `save(x, file="data.Rda")` #script2 `x = load('data.Rda')` ; `y=get(x`) ; `rm(x)`   , should it work?

Comment: You don’t “call” variables, you call *functions*. You can *use* variables. Similarly, you don’t “call into” a script. This terminology might seem pedantic but the distinction is crucial: It’s unclear what you actually want to achieve. The code you’ve posted also doesn’t help us understand your problem, since it unfortunately doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: I tried to find an issue with the optional arguments in `source` but I can't figure out. I think I don't really understand what do you mean by "optional arguments"

Comment: Any help? I just want to share/use my `combs` variables into my two script.R .. But I didn't find anything to solve my problem